# Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1380)

Tags: matlab

I have function to compute the sample mean and variance of an image's channels using sliding window operator in matlab, and create scatter plots of the mean and variance. This is the sliding window function. The channel size is 1380x1842, and h=8, w=8.

```
function [m, v] = window(channel, h, w)
  [r,c] = size(channel);

  for i = 1:c-h
      for j = 1:r-w
          M = channel(i:(i+h)-1,j:(j+w)-1);
          m(i) = mean(M(:));
          v(i) = sum(double(M(:))-repmat((m(i)),h*w,1))/(h*w);
      end
  end
  figure,
  scatter(m,v);
  end
```

When I run this I get the error saying it exceeds array bounds. I tried to work it out by hand, it seems correct.Any reason why it shows this error?

Comment: `i` is looping through `c` which is 1842, but being used for the first index which only goes up through 1380.  You've got the roles of `r` and `c` (or `i` and `j`) switched.

Comment: Thank you! changed it. Could you tell if this function achieves what the question says? I.e, is this a sliding window operator that computes the sample mean and variance of an image's channels?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation that might help. It is important when implementing sliding windows to ensure that the window does not spill over (exceed) the bounds of the `Channel`. The for-loops must take into account that the `Window_Height` and `Window_Width`. Not too sure about the variance functions/calculation, for now I've used the built-in function.

```
Image = rgb2gray(imread("peppers.png"));
Channel = single(imresize(Image,[1380 1842]));
[Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns] = size(Channel);

Window_Height = 8;
Window_Width = 8;

Means = [];
Variances = [];

Index = 1;
for Row = 1: Number_Of_Rows - Window_Height + 1
   for Column = 1: Number_Of_Columns - Window_Width + 1
    Window = Channel(Row:Row+Window_Height-1,Column:Column+Window_Width-1);
    Means(Index) = mean(Window,'all');
    Variances(Index) = var(Window,1,'all');
    Index = Index + 1;
   end
end

scatter(Means,Variances);
xlabel("Mean"); ylabel("Variance");
```